# Inserting Different length lists in PrettyTable Python

Tags: python, prettytable

```
titles =('IP','URL')
t = PrettyTable([])
list1 = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.8.8', ]
list2 = ['http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example.com', ]
for title,lst in zip(titles,itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2,fillvalue="")):
    t.add_column(title,lst)

print t
```

Display the code outputs:

[image: What the code provides]

Display that I actually want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Care to share `list1` and `list2`?

Comment: done. I forgot my bad.